# How to overcome an unexpected delay in comparator implementation in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm building a quite complicated model in Simulink. And I've noticed an unexpected delay. For simplicity, I've built a very simple model and I've found that again an unexpected delay was introduced.

The simple model is just a comparator. It's defined inside a *Matlab Function Block* as:

```
if u >= 2
  y = 3;
elseif (u < 2)
  y = -3;
```

The output is:

[image]

As you can see, the blue wave doesn't move directly from +3 to -3 or from -3 to +3. However, there is a delay like 100 *usec.* **Why is this??** I mean according to the above function, it should move right away (change abruptly). ***And how can I make it change abruptly?***

Comment: Decrease the *tolerances of your variable step solver* or the *step size, in case you use a fixed step solver.*

Comment: I'm NOT  using any step resolver or anything like that. I'm ONLY  using the above-mentioned code. Please clarify more.

Comment: Well but that code is included in a matlab function block within a simulink model, isn't it? So you're using Simulink, which is calling a solver. [And this solver you need to configure](http://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/gui/solver-pane.html). The frequency of your sine is pretty high and the output you get is to be expected with the default solver settings. Adjust the solver and everything will be fine.

Comment: Thansk, that helped :)

Comment: You may write your comment in a more detailed way as an answer so I mark it as accepted and it helps others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The frequency of your sine is pretty high. Though the (usually) default *variable-step* solver of Simulink can handle a lot of cases, the tolerances are set in absolute values. In your case the minimal step size the variable step solver is allowed to use (be means of the tolerances) is exactly the ramp you can see in your plot.

For high frequency models you need to **reduce the step size of the solver**, either directly for fixed step solvers or by adjust the tolerances in case of variable step solvers.

[image]

[image]

Leaving everything at `auto` will in most cases lead to a stable result, with realistic results, but optically you're may not satisfied. So as always **explicit is better than implicit**. You should always think about what step sizes you actually need. Sample and switching frequencies, eigenfrequencies, the desired spectrum or the desired order of harmonics are good indicators for a proper choice of the solver and the step size.